# No compatible targets were found... real device, eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm performing http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html
When I'm trying

> Run on a Real Device

from Eclipse I get

> Android AVD Error

with

> No compatible targets were found...

Why it tries to run on AVD if I have connected real device? How to fix it?

Comment: make sure usb debuging is on, on ur device sdkversion of ur app should be less or equal to ur device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First right click of on your project 
->Run As -> Run configration
[image]

Now Select the Target Tab and Click Radio button "Always Prompt to pick up the device"
[image]

Now you should have to install Google Usb Driver from the SDK manager.
[image]

Now you must allow usb debugging on device.Go to Settings->Application->Development(on API level 10).Also one more thing your min/max/target must be equal to your device(android:targetSdkVersion="10") in your AndroidManifest.xml.

[image]

After Doing these steps again run your app from eclipse with your mobile connected you will find your mobile like this
[image]

Comment: Got error - http://androidforums.com/android-applications/507701-google-usb-driver-package-not-compatible-linux.html

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install your phone android device.
Did you already installed it?
Device manager should look like this - http://s9.postimg.org/4s0s0ope7/Capture.png

Answer (score 1):

There is a few possibilites. First make sure you install USB Driver. You can see if you install it by right clicking on your Computer > Manage > Device Manager. Then see if there is your Android Device. If not go to your SDK folder > extras > Google then usb_driver. Install that.

Answer (score 1):

Change usb port if it doesn't work try change the cable even if ht e good .don't ask me why this is happening .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device Android version is the same or greater than your min SDK specified in your Manifest. Also make sure you have enabled your devices Developer mode. Settings->Developer->USB Debugging->ON.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it....
if you are using samsung you need to install **samsung kies**