# No compatible targets were found ( Android )

Tags: android, eclipse

I can't run my android programs on my device, I followed all the steps in that link  : [No compatible targets were found... real device, eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824120/no-compatible-targets-were-found-real-device-eclipse)

but I still couldn't find my device

I have a Samsung Galaxy S+ GT-I9001

Android version : 2.3.5

Target/min/max versions set on Eclipse 2.3.3(Ginger Bread)

I don't want to use a virtual device.

Help !!

Comment: have you tried to increase the max version target ?

Comment: I just did, didn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

Its likely one of two things.

1. Your debug mode isnt enabled on your phone, so eclipse will not recognise it.
2. Or your PC doesnt have the USB driver installed, so your PC does not recognise it.

Go to `Settings` -> `Developer` -> `USB Debugging` and enable it. (check its enabled).

Else, download the USB Drivers for your device.

I think these links are correct:

[HTC](http://www.htc.com/www/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx)

[SAMSUNG](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/SAMSUNG-USB-Driver-for-Mobile-Phones-1590.shtml)

Else google your phone, and android USB Driver.

Comment: Debug mode was enabled;

drivers are already installed;

basically the ADB don't recognise any device, I tried with another samsung galaxy s3 that works well on another computer but not in mine !!

Answer (score 0):

You might have problems with your USB drivers.  Try to Install [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) from their website, USB drivers should be installed then.

Comment: Already tried it and updated my phone but no use, the ADB still doesn't recognise my phone