# Android development: No compatible AVD or devices?

Tags: android, device, android-virtual-device

I am getting the following error in my console in eclipse when I try to run my application on my Samsung S4 phone:

```
[2014-06-30 13:49:53 - Multapply] Android Launch!
[2014-06-30 13:49:53 - Multapply] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-30 13:49:53 - Multapply] Performing com.example.multapply.Splash activity launch
[2014-06-30 13:49:53 - Multapply] No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.
```

This is strange as I ran the application yesterday without any problems. I am also sure that debugging is enabled on my phone?

Comment: Kill adb and start again

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: hmmm check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824120/no-compatible-targets-were-found-real-device-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

First verify whether your device is connected or not by giving following command:
'adb devices'
It should show your device name along with state as 'device'.

If your device is not displaying then try these commands,
'adb kill-server'
'adb start-server'